# How to continue switch case program, while asking user, do you want to continue (yes or no)?

Tags: java, swing, loops, joptionpane

Here is the code:

```
    import javax.swing.*;

public class SwitchCase {

    /** * @param args */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int dec = 0, num, rem, org, pow, length = 0, i = 1, input;
        LOOPA: {
            input = Integer
                    .parseInt(JOptionPane
                            .showInputDialog("Press 1 for binary to decimal conversion \n "
                                    + "Press 2 for decimal to binary conversion\n"
                                    + "Press 3 for octal to decimal conversion\n"
                                    + "Press 4 for decimal to octal conversion\n"));

            switch (input) {

            case 1:
                num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                        .showInputDialog("Enter binary number"));
                org = num;
                while (num != 0) {
                    num = num / 10;
                    length++;
                }
                pow = length - 1;
                System.out.print("decimal Equivalent is: ");
                while (pow >= 0) {
                    rem = org % 10;
                    dec = dec + (rem * i);
                    i = i * 2;
                    pow--;
                    org = org / 10;
                }
                System.out.print(dec);
                break LOOPA;

            // decimal to binary conversion

            case 2:
                int addTwo = 2,
                bin;
                num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                        .showInputDialog("Enter decimal number"));

                while (num != 0) {
                    rem = num % 2;
                    num = num / 2;

                    addTwo = (addTwo * 10) + rem;
                }
                System.out.print("Binary Equivalent is: ");

                while (addTwo != 2) {
                    bin = addTwo;
                    bin = bin % 10;
                    System.out.print(bin);
                    addTwo = addTwo / 10;
                }
                break LOOPA;

            case 3: // octal to decimal conversion

                num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                        .showInputDialog("Enter octal number"));
                org = num;
                while (num != 0) {
                    num = num / 10;
                    length++;
                }
                pow = length - 1;
                System.out.print("decimal Equivalent is: ");
                while (pow >= 0) {
                    rem = org % 10;
                    dec = dec + (rem * i);
                    i = i * 8;
                    pow--;
                    org = org / 10;
                }
                System.out.print(dec);

                break LOOPA; // decimal to octal conversion

            case 4:
                int addEight = 8,
                octal;
                num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                        .showInputDialog("Enter decimal number"));

                while (num != 0) {
                    rem = num % 8;
                    num = num / 8;

                    addEight = (addEight * 10) + rem;
                }
                System.out.print("Octal Equivalent is: ");

                while (addEight != 8) {
                    octal = addEight;
                    octal = addEight % 10;
                    System.out.print(octal);

                    addEight = addEight / 10;
                }
                break LOOPA;
            default:
                System.out.print("do u want to continue");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aehm - please format that (shows some effort). There is a code icon in the editor.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't want to go through this code. Badly formatted.

Comment: If you narrow your code down to a small piece that demonstrates your question it will be easier to receive help on it.

Comment: Have a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749522/bubble-sort-of-a-double-linked-list-doesnt-stop-running/8749764#8749764)

Comment: Kindly accept and upvote an answer that correctly or approximately answered your question.

Answer (score 3):

Since your code is a bit too much unformatted to be understood, here's a simple work through of your problem. Try and work on these lines:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s;
switch(yourVariable)
{

      case 1:
      //do something
      System.out.println("Do you wish to continue(y/n)?");
      s = br.readLine();
      if(s.equals("n"))
               break;


      //so on
}
```

*but how can i use it outside switch statement?*

```
do
{
    switch(yourVariable)
          {

          }
    System.out.println("Do you wish to continue(y/n)?");
    s = br.readLine();
}while(s.equals("y");
```

Comment: but how can i use it outside switch statement?

Comment: Great edit.  Not sure if the OP has noticed it.

Comment: Most probably he hasn't.

Answer (score 2):

> How to continue switch case program, while asking user, do you want to continue ( yes or no)?

Use a loop.

Comment: Can you format your code so it does not make me go cross-eyed?  My head is still spinning from the 1st edit I did..

Comment: it is just a switch case program, you just need to tell how can i repeated use it while asking from user, is he want to continue or not. just that

Comment: You just need to understand that the people who are helping you for free expect some effort on your part.  Just (start with) that.